# MySQL Cluster - [ [ndbd] ERROR -- Couldn't start as daemon, error: 'Failed to open logfile ]

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, ubuntu-10.04

recently I want to set up mysql cluster, one Mgmt node, one sql node and two data node,
it seems successfully installed and Mgmt node started, but when I try to start data node, I hit a problem...

here is the error message when I try to start data node:

[image: error message from my datanode]

Does anyone know what's going wrong? 
basically I follow the step by step tutorial on [this site](http://napmas.blogspot.tw/2011/07/mysql-cluster.html) and [this site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster.html)

It would be very appreciated if you can give me some advice!
thanks

Comment: If you create the directory that is missing, does it continue ok?

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that before, and it still got error...
is it possible that has somethings about authority?

I set the directory 'mysql_cluster' is belong to the group 'mysql' in my  Mgmt node

Comment: I dont think it is rights related because you are running it as root via sudo.  Though if it changes user context in the app, I suppose so.

Comment: okay...so what is exactly the problem...
I still stuck here!

Comment: @Arvin were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue but unable to fix it. If yes, can you post the solution?

Comment: I did resolve this problem, and my solution is chmod some files,

chown and chmod your mysql dictionary
sudo chown mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/mysql/data

as I remember, I use the command above, hope it can help you...
I also re-setup my sqlnode couple times, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I came up with a solution to fix this issue : `013-01-18 09:26:10 [ndbd] ERROR    -- Couldn't start as daemon, error: 'Failed to open logfile`

I was stuck with the same issue and after exploring I opened the `$MY_CLUSTER_INSTALLATION/ndb_data/ndb_1_cluster.log`

1.I found the following message present in the log:

```
2013-01-18 09:24:50 [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Got initial configuration 
from 'conf/config.ini',
will try to set it when all ndb_mgmd(s) started
2013-01-18 09:24:50 [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Node 1: Node 1 Connected
2013-01-18 09:24:54 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Unable to bind management 
service port: *:1186!
Please check if the port is already used,
(perhaps a ndb_mgmd is already running),
and if you are executing on the correct computer
2013-01-18 09:24:54 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Failed to start mangement service!
```

2.I checked the services running on port on my Mac machine using following command:

```
lsof -i :1186
```

And sure enough, I found the ndb_mgmd(s):

```
COMMAND  PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ndb_mgmd 418     8u  IPv4 0x33a882b4d23b342d      0t0  TCP *:mysql-cluster (LISTEN)
ndb_mgmd 418     9u  IPv4 0x33a882b4d147fe85      0t0  TCP localhost:50218->localhost:mysql-cluster (ESTABLISHED)
ndb_mgmd 418    10u  IPv4 0x33a882b4d26901a5      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql-cluster->localhost:50218 (ESTABLISHED)
```

3.To kill the processes on the specific port (for me : 1186) I ran following command:

```
sof -P | grep '1186' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

4.I repeated the steps listed in mySql Cluster installation pdf again:

```
$PATH/mysqlc/bin/ndb_mgmd -f conf/config.ini --initial --configdir=/$PATH/my_cluster/conf/
$PATH/mysqlc/bin/ndbd -c localhost:1186
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful
In my case, two data node were connected already

you can check this out in your management node

```
[root@ab0]# ndb_mgm  
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --  
ndb_mgm> show
```

what i did was

```
ndb_mgm> shutdown
```

and then execute the restart command. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Check that the datadir exists and is writeable with "ls -ld /home/netdb/mysql_cluster/data" on datanode1.